# Concentrating a join into a single column in linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
    var query = (from wo in _dbContext.WorkOrder
                 join opr in _dbContext.Operation
                 on wo.operationID equals opr.operationID
                 where wo.orderid == selectedorderid
                 select new {wo.orderid, wo.workOrderID, wo.itemID, wo.operationID, opr.operationName, wo.operationCode}).ToList();
```

I also have another table,which joins with workorder table,and returns multiple values.

What I want to do is,I want to join the table and get a single column of it as a concentrated column in my query such as (id1,id2,id3) etc. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what is the problem you can add one more join in your query !

Comment: yes,but it would duplicate the results.I need them in a single concentrated column.

Comment: ohhk can you please share your table structure and column name which you want.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by *concentrated* column, more specifically, what would be the **type** of that "column" (property).

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You want to join `IDs` of `Operations`  into a single `string` that have corresponding `WorkOrder`? In other words, `WorkOrder1, (Operation1_Id, Operation2_Id, Operation3_Id, ...)`? If that's the case, you have to `GroupBy` on `workOrderID` and `String.Join(", ", Operations)`.

Comment: I see,I'll write what I want to do in SQL.

Comment: You can do the same thing in C# too. Let me drop a quick answer.

Comment: Actually all i want is groupconcat as in mysql :P

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var query = (from wo in _dbContext.WorkOrder
                 join opr in _dbContext.Operation
                 on wo.operationID equals opr.operationID
                 where wo.orderid == selectedorderid
                 select new {wo.orderid, wo.workOrderID, wo.itemID, wo.operationID, opr.operationName, wo.operationCode}).ToList();

var orders = queryGroupBy(i => i.workOrderID)
                .Select(i => new {WorkOrderId = i.workOrderID, ConcatinatedIds = String.Join(", ", i.Select(j => j.operationID))})
                .ToList();
```